# Function called from another package cannot access to parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest

Here is my problem :

I'm having two classes: class A contains some `@Value("${param.username}")` and `@Value("${param.password}")`, I have a function using those 2 params, and I a use `@GetMapping(path = "/functionA")` to run the functionA (this function is a Post request to a server to authentificate)

Username and password are on `application-contextual-values.properties`

When I run on browser `localhost:8080/app/functionA` => it works !

I have another class B, on another package B, I want to call the first class A and use the fuctionA to authentificate. => I'm having an error : `Username must not be null`

It means that I cannot get `username` and `password` that are stored in `application-contextual-values` file.

Here is my code of class A :

```
public class A {

    @Value("${param.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${param.password}")
    private String password;

    @GetMapping(path = "functionA")
    public AuthentificationModel getClient() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth(this.username, this.password);
        String jwt = getJWT(); <======  this function is also in this class A
        
        ...
     
        I'm doing a construction of params, to send on POST 

        return token;
     }
```

The `AuthentificationModel`  is just what is sent back after the POST request (access_token, client_id, token_type)

My class B is :

```
import fr.ag2rlamondiale.ytb.rest.A; <==== class A

public class B {

   private static Map<String, String> getRequestHeader() {

       Map<String, String> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();
       try{
         final A objA = new A(); <===== instance of my class A here
           String token = objA.getClient().getAccessToken(); <==== getClient() is the funct that returns token on class A

           requestHeaders.put("Authorization", "Bearer ", + token); 
             
           ... many other put for header
         } catch (CommonException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return requestHeaders;
}
```

My application-contextual-values.properties :

```
param.username="kljkjsdf555sdf"
param.password="xxx222xxx"
```

Is it because I'll need to add constructor on class A with params username and password ? what is the proper way to make it work in my context ?

Edit :

In class A I added : @Controller

In class B : I added `@Authowired A objA` and no `new A();`

But now, having a new error : `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field objA`

Meaning that elements on class A are non-static and I'm using objA as a static object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Dependency injection and @Autowired Your `A` instance in `B` and don't create new Instance of `A` in your `B` class.

Comment: I did some edit in my question. Now after @ Autowired my A in B, an error that suggesting me to make @ Autowired static A appears

Comment: Why `getRequestHeader` should be static?

Comment: Class `B` can be another `Component` with non-static method `getRequestHeader`.

Comment: Put `@Component` annotation above `B` class an `@Authowired` it anywhere else you want to use it.

Comment: Works ! getRequestHeader shouldn't be static yes!

Answer (score 0):

Spring can process only the objects that it manages (read creates), including resolution / injection of data annotated with `@Value` of course.

When you create the instance of class `A` by yourself from class B:

```
final A objA = new A();
```

Spring has no idea that this class must be processed, in fact it doesn't even know that this class exists, hence the "value" in not injected/set.

In  general to solve this, you need to refactor your code.
Its not clear why do you create the class of Controller (I assume that `A` is a controller because it's method `getClient` is annotated with `@GetMapping` which makes sense only in controllers).

However, you don't have to create an instance of A, but rather inject it and make sure that both `A` and `B` are managed by Spring

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating instance of A using `A objA = new A()` in class B, spring does not inject any value in class A as it is new object. To use property injection in class A, you need to use dependency injection and use bean of A already instantiated using spring application context.

I assume Class A is annotated with @Controller.

```
@Controller
public class A {
```

and use autowiring in class B like below to inject instance of A

```
public class B {

   @Autowired
   A objA;

   private static Map<String, String> getRequestHeader() {

       Map<String, String> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();
       try{
         //final A objA = new A(); <===== instance of my class A here
           String token = objA.getClient().getAccessToken(); <==== getClient() is the funct that returns token on class A
```

Comment: Thanks Thaker , yes I forgot @Controller on class A, but now, by Autowired on class B, I'm having an error : "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field objA" when I do : @ Autowired static A ObjA; then after compilation I have error 403 when I access to localhost:8080/app/functionA

Comment: @hek_ it is because method getRequestHeader is static method while Autowired object is non-static.